# Dividing a group of $2n$ people, of whom $n$ are male and $n$ are female, into equal groups so that each group has at least one female

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is as follows

> Of $2n$ people, $n$ are male and $n$ are female. How many ways are there of dividing them into 2 equal sized groups where each has at least one female person? Assume the groups are indistinguishable.

As a preliminary step I have worked out that the number of ways to divide them simply into 2 equal sized groups is

$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Can anyone provide a hint? Thank you

Comment: Hint: how many ways can you divide them so that a group has zero females?

Answer (score 1):

Pretend that the groups are distinguishable.  Then, at the end of the computation, apply the $~\dfrac{1}{2}~$ factor.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}~$ ways of dividing the people into two distinguishable groups.  Of these groupings, there are only $(2)$ unsatisfactory groupings:

- Group 1 has all women.
- Group 2 has all women.

So, the final computation is

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \left[\binom{2n}{n} - 2\right].$$